# Were there Unix equivalents to BBSes?

Tags: history

During the 1980s and 1990s [Bulletin Board Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletin_board_system) (BBS) were widely used on all kinds of computers. The [BBS Documentary](https://archive.org/details/BBS.The.Documentary/) documents the rise and fall of the BBS subculture.

Watching this documentary left me wondering about Unix systems. They are - similar to BBS - designed to support remote TTYs over a modem, using `getty` and `login` to provide access to the system.

Does there exist any record of a *publicly accessible* Unix system during the 1980s and 1990s that people could call into using a modem?

Comment: Without registering in advance?

Comment: Any answer is welcome, I'd just like to know whether accessing Unix systems remotely was "a thing" like BBSes were in those days.

Comment: It depends on what "publicly accessible" means. I don't think there were any that would just let anyone in, but e.g. webhosting services were widely available from the 90s onwards.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. But were there pre-WWW Unix systems that people could access?

Comment: There certainly were Unix-running BBS systems. Which ran which I do not know, but you can see a list of BBS software for Unix [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BBS_software#Unix_and_compatible).

Comment: As a sixth-former in UK school (approximate age 17-18) in the early 1980s I had a login to three of the local polytechnic (university) timesharing systems. One of those was UNIX. I don't recall if logins were publicly available or if it was arranged through my college.

Comment: There were even BBSes that ran on Unix. A couple of their users and sysops appeared in that documentary.

Comment: Also what does "access" mean? Get a shell, or access some software that's running on it (e.g. a BBS).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even before they were routinely interconnected, Unix systems could be considered as effectively their own BBSes. They were usually multi-user systems, and they allowed their users to swap files, and exchange messages (initially as a specific use of shared files). Users didn’t have to connect to a separate BBS.

Interconnecting Unix systems, whether permanently or intermittently (using [UUCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUCP)), provided an extension to this, and protocols were created to allow users to share files with users on other systems, and to send and receive messages to and from users on other systems. Successive changes to protocols and new protocols provided more and more indirection, for example going from bang paths for email to the present-day DNS-based system.

There was one significant difference between BBSes as seen from micros, and Unix systems: the former tended to favour asynchronous use, since only a small number of users could be connected simultaneously (compared to the overall number of users), whereas the latter also allowed synchronous messaging systems (starting with [`write`](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/write) which was already present in V1 Unix) and related programs. This led in particular to the emergence of [MUDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD) (multi-user dungeons) and the communities surrounding them; these were nominally multi-user text-based games, but often users were interested more in chatting with other users than actually playing the game. (MUDs weren’t only available on Unix systems; [Micronet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micronet_800) in particular in the UK offered one which was accessible over [Prestel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prestel).)

Many Unix systems also provided dial-up access; this was fairly straightforward since modems could be considered as extensions of the serial lines used to connect terminals to Unix systems. I don’t know of any which had the same access patterns as BBSes; most would have provided dial-up access for regular users working from home (although logins could of course be shared, or given out more widely than the bean-counters intended), and some provided commercial access to specific services.

Many early ISPs effectively provided dial-up connectivity to Unix systems; but the latter weren’t the end-users’ target, they were simply a hop on the way to the rest of the Internet, either directly (for interactive protocols) or indirectly (for email, Usenet etc.).

Comment: Don't forget the good ole days of NNTP!

Comment: @mikem I still use NNTP ;-). I included it as part of Usenet...

Comment: Usenet is still widely used - typically 100+TBytes/month

Answer (score 5):

[SDF Public Access Unix](https://sdf.org/) has been offering dialup access of some sort to UNIX shells since 1987 and *still* offers dialup today (now as a paid service).

> Members have UNIX shell access to games, email, usenet, chat, bboard,
> webspace, gopherspace, programming utilities, archivers, browsers, and
> more. The SDF community is made up of caring, highly skilled people who
> operate behind the scenes to maintain a non-commercial INTERNET.

Comment: Here's the actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

There were two reasons to use a BBS in the 80s.

1. [Warez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warez)
2. [FidoNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FidoNet)

The Internet made both obsolete in the 90s.

The FidoNet got replaced by E-Mail and the [Usenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet). In the beginning dialup connections were used with [UUCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUCP) which implements a batch transfer similar to [FrontDoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FrontDoor) or BinkleyTerm. Later on direct connections where used with [PPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol). This made it possible to use [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) and [NNTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_News_Transfer_Protocol) directly. But the Internet had much more than a BBS: for example [IRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) and later on [WWW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web). Those who where still interested in Warez where happy with Newsgroups and [uuencode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) or IRC bots. And the other used instead 30 floppy disks [Slackware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slackware), which contained so much free software, it was a cockaigne. With Slackware it was possible to run on a [486](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80486) home computer the same [OPEN LOOK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPEN_LOOK) GUI, which was running on the expensive [SPARCstations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARCstation) in the university. At that point I did not use DOS and Frontdoor anymore. BBS's became obsolete.

A PC running Linux connected via [Ping e.V.](https://secure.ping.de/index_eng.html) to the Internet of the local university was (at least for me) the successor to a PC running DOS connecting to a local BBS.

So there are many similarities but I would not call it equivalence.

Comment: I am slowly beginning to realize the the _Internet_ could be seen as the Unix-based equivalent of a BBS...

Comment: there were also doors

Comment: And there were message boards where you could actually talk to people.